# How to install GWT browser plugin?

Tags: google-chrome, gwt, plugins

How do I install the [GWT browser plugin for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/gwt-developer-plugin/jpjpnpmbddbjkfaccnmhnkdgjideieim)? It says

> This application is not supported on this computer. Installation has been disabled.

Has GWT been abandoned? I'm using Chrome Version 29.0.1547.76 m and Windows 8.

Comment: Never tried it on Win 8, but it's always worked for me on Win7 x64. It's possible they don't support Win 8. If so, you could always GWT Compile your project, run dev mode, and leave out the `?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997` portion of the URL. Unfortunately, you must compile every time you want to use that since you're leaving out the code server.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Solution: https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=7778#c5

```
Sweet, I just got the Dev Mode plugin to work on Chrome too, Windows 8.  Here's what I did:

1. Make sure Chrome is pined to the task bar
2. Right click on the chrome icon>Properties>Shortcut
3. Add in target: --enable-easy-off-store-extension-install
4. Open chrome and navigate to extensions ( chrome://chrome/extensions/ )
5. Drag and drop on it the plugin (I've attached it)

I was able to download the plugin from here:  https://groups.google.com/group/google-web-toolkit/attach/d1c909bf4c5cbfb4/gwt-dev-plugin.crx?part=4&authuser=0

In case that link goes away, Here's the chat post that led me to the solution: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/google-web-toolkit/jDg3KoXoVPc/tL9cTL8JydEJ
```

You have to right click on the Chrome icon twice for Windows 8, opening Extensions tab was unnecessary, the Drag & Drop was not needed, and the link will re-direct to another link.

Answer (score 5):

Just set the compatibility mode of chrome to windows 7. Then it is possible to install the plugin and to use it.

Comment: Simplest Solution, would accept this answer if i where OP. Thank you