# GWT Dev Mode Plugin Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, gwt, browser

Sorry if this is posted in the wrong place but I'm trying to find a download link for the old GWT Dev Mode plugin on the Chrome browser, however the link to the google store appears to be dead. Anyone got a location online I could get it from ?

Thanks.

Comment: see this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29743214/development-mode-requires-the-gwt-developer-plugin/29747647#29747647 ,http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29750514/gwt-plugin-doesnt-work-in-chrome-42/29751058#29751058, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33730959/gwt-plugin-issue-in-chrome/33753094#33753094

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The link was purposely removed, because the plugin does not work with chrome anymore.

Some googling lead me to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19059544/how-to-install-gwt-browser-plugin) which lead me to [this discussion](https://code.google.com/archive/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/7778#c5) which contains several links to old versions of the plugin, including [this one](https://groups.google.com/group/google-web-toolkit/attach/d1c909bf4c5cbfb4/gwt-dev-plugin.crx?part=4&authuser=0).

But I'm very dubious about why you need this plugin. The only way it would work is if you have a very old version of Chrome, and at that point I'm not sure why you're testing via the plugin anyway. You should be using [Super Dev Mode](http://www.gwtproject.org/articles/superdevmode.html) instead.

Comment: Hi Kevin, unfortunately my application is a .WAR file and I was lead to believe Super Dev mode doesn't support deployments like that.